# Size of group of roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $G=(\mathbb{Z}/p^N\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Let $a=p^{N-1}$, $b=p-1$,  $A=\{g\in G: g^{a}=1\}$, $B=\{g\in G: g^{b}=1\}$.

Prove that $A,B$ are subgroups of size $a,b$ respectively.

It is easy to show that $A,B$ are subgroups but I am stuck at proving the sizes of $A,B$. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: The fact that G is a cyclic group cannot be used since this question will be used to demonstrate the fact later on.

Comment: It depends on how much you know about finite abelian groups. $G$ is a finite abelian group of order $ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime. That by itself implies that $G = A \times B$, without needing to know anything else about $G$.

Comment: I realize that upon establishing the sizes of $A,B$ we can have $G=A \times B$, but the question is in proving the size of $A,B$ are $a,b$ respectively

Comment: Every element  $g \in G$ has order dividing $ab$, so we can write $g=g_1g_2$ where the orders of $g_1$ and $g_2$ divide $a$ and $b$. So $g_1 \in A$, $g_2 \in B$, and $G=AB$. Since $A \cap B = 1$, $G = A \times B$.

Comment: ok so now we have $G=A \times B$, how do we deduce the sizes of $A,B$ then?

Comment: That's clear because $|G| = |A| \times |B|$.

Comment: But isn't it possible that $|A|=b, |B|=a$ or some other 'factorization' of $ab$?

Comment: Actually by considering elements of form $1+xp$, I have managed to show that $|A| \geq a$. So more precisely, now I only need to eliminate the case that $|A|=ab_1, |B|=b_2$, where $b=b_1b_2$, $b_1,b_2>1$

Comment: Do you not Cauchy's Theorem? If a group has order divisible by a prime $p$ then it has an element of order $p$. So $|A|$ is coprime to $b$ and hence $|A|=a$.

Comment: I get how to complete the remaining steps, thanks a lot!